# How to make stateful Clojure code pure without excessive repetition?

Tags: clojure, state, clojurescript, voronoi, delaunay

I'm writing a Clojure library to generate Voronoi diagrams using the quad-edge data structure as described in [this research paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/282918.282923). I was using refs to represent the edge records, but I wanted to change the code to be pure for a couple reasons:

- I don't want users of the library to have to worry about details like wrapping their code in a `dosync`.
- I want to be able to make non-destructive updates, such as clipping a diagram to a viewport without altering the original triangulation.
- Refs are not implemented in Clojurescript.

The problem is that the pure code is extremely repetitive due to passing around the data structure to every single function. Here's an example:

```
(defn- bubble-up [qeds cross]
  (loop [qeds qeds
         cross cross]
    (let [l-edge (first-hit qeds cross (q/r-prev qeds cross) q/o-next)
          r-edge (first-hit qeds cross (q/o-prev qeds cross) q/o-prev)
          l-valid (above? qeds l-edge cross)
          r-valid (above? qeds r-edge cross)]
      (when (or l-valid r-valid)
        (let [[qeds new-cross]
              (if (or (not l-valid)
                      (and r-valid
                           (in-circle? (dest qeds l-edge) (org qeds l-edge) (org qeds r-edge)
                                       (dest qeds r-edge))))
                (connect qeds r-edge (q/sym cross))
                (connect qeds (q/sym cross) (q/sym l-edge)))]
          (recur qeds new-cross))))))
```

I've tried various other approaches, including:

- Writing the mutable part in Java.
- Using a state monad (which is slightly better but still clunky and not idiomatic.)
- Putting the data structure in a dynamic var.

Is there a standard, idiomatic way to deal with a situation like this in Clojure(script)?

Comment: Check out [atoms](https://clojure.org/reference/atoms) for keeping mutable state.

Comment: How would you ideally implement `bubble-up` if you were to use an imperative language, say Python? What would that code look like and in what way would that code be any less repetitive?

Comment: @Rulle If I were to implement it in Python, each edge would be its own object with references to other edges, so I wouldn't need the central data structure qeds to store them all (The quad-edge data structure is basically a collection of circular linked lists which seems hard to represent in Clojure without mutable references.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a standard, idiomatic way to deal with a situation like this in Clojure(script)?

Can't judge for all, but I would leave things as they are.
And at the risk of stating the obvious, if some particular set of forms (that's not just a single function call) can be seen in more than 2 places, it probably deserves to be extracted into its own function. But the presented code doesn't have something like that.

If you dislike that repetition to such an extent that something *must* be done, as an alternative you can create a function that's like `partial` but upside-down:

```
(defn bind [obj & fns]
  (mapv #(prepare % obj) fns))
```

And then use it as:

```
(let [[first-hit r-prev o-prev above?]
      (bind qeds first-hit o/r-prev o/o-prev above?)]

      l-edge (first-hit cross (r-prev cross) q/o-next)
      r-edge (first-hit cross (o-prev cross) q/o-prev)
      l-valid (above? l-edge cross)
      r-valid (above? r-edge cross)]
  ...)
```

Whether it's worth it  or not is up to you. I probably wouldn't do it, unless there were many more similar lines with repeated usages of the same functions.

As a yet another alternative, you could use a dynamic variable to store the graph. But in some regards it might be even worse than a refs/atoms-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapv` to factor common code:

```
(defn- bubble-up [qeds cross]
  (let [[l-edge r-edge] (mapv #(first-hit qeds cross (q/r-prev qeds cross) %) [q/o-next q/o-prev])
        [l-valid r-valid] (mapv #(above? qeds % cross) [l-edge r-edge])]
    (when (or l-valid r-valid)
      (let [right-handed? (if (or (not l-valid)
                                  (and r-valid
                                       (in-circle? (dest qeds l-edge) (org qeds l-edge) (org qeds r-edge) (dest qeds r-edge)))))
            [new-qeds new-cross] (if right-handed?
                                   (connect qeds r-edge (q/sym cross))
                                   (connect qeds (q/sym cross) (q/sym l-edge)))]
        (recur new-qeds new-cross)))))
```

Other simplifications:

- There is no need for the `loop`. The function `bubble-up` is a `recur` target.
- Extract the complex condition into a local binding.

None of this addresses the major problem: `qeds` is passed in as an argument to every function, and - worse - has to be passed out again by `connect` in a data structure.

Zach Tellman wrote [Proteus](https://github.com/ztellman/proteus) to provide efficient (local) mutable bindings. It no longer works.

Answer (score -1):

Your use case is a good candidate for using a dynamic Var.  A good example can be seen in the [Tupelo Forest library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/tupelo/forest.clj#L79). In cases like this, a global variable can reduce clutter in function calls.

However, global variables are often a bad idea. Their use hides dependencies between different functions. This can result in concise, tight code that is easier to read. However, ***it assumes you know about the coupling*** due to the global variable.

[Here is a good discussion](https://stuartsierra.com/2013/03/29/perils-of-dynamic-scope) of the cost/benefit tradeoff for dynamic Vars.

My conclusion?  Sometimes the benefit outweighs the cost, other times it doesn't.  For my limited understanding of your use case, I would use a dynamic Var. If you change your mind later, then change it back to an explicit function parameter.

---

P.S. When I do pass explicit params through a call chain, I usually wrap them all up into a single map named `ctx` (a short semi-standard name for "context"), and pass that as the first parameter to each function.